# How do I read from cin until it is empty?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read pairs of lines from a file passed in through the cin.
I need to read until the file is empty.
If one line of the pair is empty, I need to save that line as "".
If both lines are empty, then both need to be saved and processed as "".

I am using the getline to read the lines in, with a while-loop that keeps going until both lines are empty.
However, I need it to continue until the file is empty, as it is possible that 2 empty lines are followed by a number of filled lines.

This is how I have it at the moment:

```
getline(cin, str1); getline(cin, str2);
while (str1 == "" | str1 != "") {
  ....
  str1 = ""; str2 = "";
  getline(cin, str1); getline(cin, str2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contains two line feeds in a row this would not work.  You can use `cin.eof()` to check when you’ve reached the end of the file.  If it returns 1 then you’ve attempted to read beyond the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you take input from a file and pass it to your c++ compiled program

```sh
cat input_file.txt | cpp_binary_executable
```

then the `cin` in a while loop will read each line till the end of the file

```cpp
    string temp;
    while (cin >> temp) //read each line till the end of file
    {
        cout << temp << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
while (getline(cin, str1) && getline(cin, str2)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or even:

```
while (getline(getline(cin, str1), str2)) {
    // ...
}
```